# Presentation of infinite differentiable functions with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The task is: Let $\phi \in C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R})$ (infinite differentiable function with compact support) and $\phi(0)=0$ Show that $\phi(x)=x \psi(x)$ for some $\psi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $x\in \mathbb R.$ Set $g(t)=f(tx).$ Then

$$f(x)= \int_0^1 f'(tx) x\, dt.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\psi(x):=\phi(x)/x$ on $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$. Of course $\psi\in C^\infty((-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty))$. Then define $\psi(0):=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\psi(x)$, because the limit exists from the l'Hopital's rule. Therefore $\psi\in C(\mathbb{R})$. Now, since the expression $$\psi'(x)=\phi'(x)x^{-1}-\phi(x)x^{-2}$$ is well-defined everywhere, (both terms can be well-defined by the l'Hopital's rule) $\psi\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$. Do this inductively, you will have the result. If you want more rigorous proof, then show $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}||\mathfrak{D}^n\psi-D_h^n\psi||_{C^0}=0,\forall n,$$ where $\mathfrak{D}f$ is the formal derivative of the $\psi$, and $D_hf=\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}.$